# I am trying to incorporate customized news feed in my website specifically for agriculture news only, but I am getting general news from portal

Tags: javascript, rss

Now when I am adding agri URL to http://www.surfing-waves.com/feed.htm,
it is displaying all the news instead of agri news.

Link to agri news:
http://www.thebetterindia.com/topics/agriculture/

How can I fetch agri news only ?

```
          <!-- start sw-rss-feed code --> 
         <script type="text/javascript"> 
         <!-- 
          rssfeed_url = new Array(); 
        rssfeed_url[0]="http://www.thebetterindia.com/topics/agriculture/";  
     rssfeed_frame_width="400"; 
       rssfeed_frame_height="260"; 
       rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
       rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
         rssfeed_scroll_bar="off"; 
            rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
             rssfeed_font_size="12"; 
          rssfeed_font_face=""; 
           rssfeed_border="on"; 
          rssfeed_css_url="https://feed.surfing-waves.com/css/style6.css"; 
        rssfeed_title="on"; 
         rssfeed_title_name=""; 
          rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
         rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
          rssfeed_title_bgimage=""; 
         rssfeed_footer="off"; 
                 rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
             rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
              rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
           rssfeed_footer_bgimage=""; 
              rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
            rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
          rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
           rssfeed_item_bgimage=""; 
          rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
         rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
            rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
             rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
           rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
           rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
            rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
         rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
               rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
              rssfeed_cache = "a7232879eaa3d05e2199d04c7c000a65"; 
           //--> 
           </script> 
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//feed.surfing-waves.com/js/rss-feed.js"></script> 
        <!-- The link below helps keep this service FREE, and helps other people find the SW widget. Please be cool and keep it! Thanks. --> 
      <div style="text-align:right; width:400px;"><a href="http://www.surfing-waves.com/feed.htm" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">feedwidget @</a> <a href="http://www.surfing-waves.com" target="_blank" style="color:#ccc;font-size:10px">Surfing Waves</a></div> 
            <!-- end sw-rss-feed code -->
```

Comment: An easier way to achieve the result you want is to use node package `cheerio`. It allows you to scrape the website and keep only what you want.

Comment: Why did you overwrite your old question? Ask a new one

Comment: My account got banned so editing the current questions which is the only way to get back the access.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference the agriculture feed directly. Use

```
rssfeed_url[0]="http://www.thebetterindia.com/topics/agriculture/feed/"
```